# How to use Component's context within setTimeout()?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm implementing `RefreshControl` in `ReactNative` app. Everything works fine, data fetching and updating.

The problem I'm facing is, most of the views take 2 second to update after fetching initial data. So before other view's data is loaded the refresh spinner is hidden. To patch fix this Im trying to add a delay before setting `refreshing: false`.

**Question: How to get the Main Component's `context` within `setTimeout()` ?**

```
onRefresh = () => {
    this.setState({ refreshing: true }); // <--- **this** here is Main Component.
    this.fetchData().then(() => {
        setTimeout(function () {
            this.setState({ refreshing: false }); // <--- Here getting error like "this.setState" is undefined.
        }, 2000);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

insert

```
var localThis=this;
```

before the line this.fetchData().then ...

and use **localThis** instead **this**

```
localThis.setState({ refreshing: false });



onRefresh = () => {
    this.setState({ refreshing: true }); // <--- **this** here is Main Component.
    var localThis=this;
    this.fetchData().then(() => {
        setTimeout(function () {
            localThis.setState({ refreshing: false }); // <--- Here getting error like "this.setState" is undefined.
        }, 2000);
    });
}
```

Comment: ...or just use arrow function inside `setTimeout`

Comment: @skyboyer : I totaly agree
Arrow functions have no “this”. As we remember from the chapter Object methods, "this", arrow functions do not have this. If this is accessed, **it is taken from the outside**.
as described here : https://javascript.info/arrow-functions#arrow-functions-have-no-this

Comment: @Eric isn't the outside this fit in the case?

Comment: @skyboyer : **yes, we have right both of us.**
you can use my way (**localThis** is in the external scope) 
or the arrow method as you describe ==> () { this.... }, **this** is in the outside scope too.. . because arrow function don't propagate the context : this.
but for the the function() {.this ..}, **this** is a new context.